# Gaussian Latent Variable Parameter Learning

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, hierarchical-bayesian, graphical-model, latent-variable

Do any approximate (preferably message passing type) inference algorithms exist for learning the parameters of a latent Gaussian variable (from information of other dependent observed variables)?

See the Bayes Network below as an example (the shaded y node is the only variable which will be observed - typically with many samples):

[image]

Y will be dependent on X through a linear gaussian function with known and constant transfer matrix and additive noise matrix.

Y = AX+Q

X~N($\mu$, $\lambda$)

A: known constant transfer matrix

Q~N(0,S)

S: known constant noise covariance matrix